# Formatting References: Journal Articles

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm trying to modify my references so that a journal article appears as "volume, number" instead of volume(number). I also need to include the DOI number. Any suggestions?

Currently, one reference looks like this:

> Andreoni, James. 1990. "Impure Altruism and Donations to Public Goods:
>   A Theory of Warm-Glow Giving" *The Economic Journal* 100(401):464-477.

What I am looking for:

> Andreoni, James. 1990. "Impure Altruism and Donations to Public Goods:
>   A Theory of Warm-Glow Giving" *The Economic Journal* 100, no.
>   401:464-477. doi: 10.2307/2234133.

I'm currently using natbib with apsr-quote.bst. I'm fairly new to LaTex so any advice would be much appreciated!

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage {inputenc, ucs, amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, latexsym, graphicx, natbib,ntheorem,setspace}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{;}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[T1,hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float}



\usepackage{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#4#5#3#6}


\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.125in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in}

\newcommand*{\TitleFont}{%
    \usefont{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}%
    \fontsize{16}{20}%
    \selectfont}
```

Bib entry (using BibDesk):

```
@article{andreoni1990impure,
    Author = {Andreoni, James},
    Journal = {The Economic Journal},
    Number = {401},
    Pages = {464--477},
    Title = {Impure Altruism and Donations to Public Goods: A Theory of Warm-Glow Giving},
    Volume = {100},
    Year = {1990}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rename the file [apsr_fsb.bst](https://www.nyu.edu/projects/beber/files/apsr_fsb.bst) and in the new renamed file do the following changes:

**1)** In the `ENTRY` you have to add to `doi` so it will become:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    URL
    volume
    year
    doi %added
  }
```

**2)** Add also the following code (you can put it directly after `INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }`):

```
FUNCTION {doilink}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "" }
{ doi empty$
    { skip$ }
    { "\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {add.doi}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { skip$ }
    { doi empty$
        {}
        {"\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{" * swap$ * "}" *}
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.jdoi}
{ doi missing$   
    { "" }
    {", doi: " doi * 
      }
    if$
     doilink 
}
```

**3)** Now replace the following code

```
FUNCTION {format.num}
{ number empty$
  'skip$
  { "(" number * ")" * *
  }
  if$
}
```

by the following one:

```
FUNCTION {format.num}
{ number empty$
  'skip$
  { ", no. " number * " " * *
  }
  if$
}
```

**4)** Finally, replace the following code

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  list.label.output
  list.year output.nonnull
  new.block
  author "author" item.check
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.title quote "title" output.check }
  if$
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" duplicate$ item.check
      year empty$
        { ". Forthcoming" * output new.block }
        { " " * format.vol.mon.num.pages * output }
      if$
     }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  fin.entry
}
```

by

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  list.label.output
  list.year output.nonnull
  new.block
  author "author" item.check
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.title quote "title" output.check }
  if$
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" duplicate$ item.check
      year empty$
        { ". Forthcoming" * output new.block }
        { " " * format.vol.mon.num.pages * output }
      if$
      format.jdoi * " " output %added
     }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output 
      format.jdoi add.doi "doi: " output  
    }
  if$
  new.block
  fin.entry
}
```

A **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage {inputenc, ucs, amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, latexsym, graphicx, natbib,ntheorem,setspace}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{;}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[T1,hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float}



\usepackage{csquotes}
%\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#4#5#3#6} 

\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{%
    #1%
    \iflanguage{english}{\itshape}{}% ADDED
    #2#4#3#6#5%
}
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{%
    \iflanguage{english}{\itshape}{}% ADDED
    #1#2#4#3%
}


\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.125in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in}

\newcommand*{\TitleFont}{%
    \usefont{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}%
    \fontsize{16}{20}%
    \selectfont}

\begin{document}
    \cite{andreoni1990impure}
    \bibliographystyle{apsr_fsb_mod}
    \bibliography{Library}
\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image]

**Update:**

For the [apsr.bst](http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/apsr.bst) style instead of **3)** you must replace the following code

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
    { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ format.pages }
    { ":" * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

by

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    {    ", no. " number * " " * *     % instead of: "(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
    { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ format.pages }
    { " : " * pages n.dashify * } % instead of: ":" * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The DOI field is now included in references. However, I am having trouble with step 3 since I wasn't able to find the FUNCTION{format.num} in the apsr.bst file. Instead, I modified the FUNCTION{format.vol.num.pages} with the same change you suggested, but this removes volume and number from the references all together. Not sure what I did wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify my above comment, my sample reference is now appearing as: Andreoni, James. 1990. “Impure Altruism and Donations to Public Goods: A Theory of Warm-Glow Giving.” The Economic Journal , doi: 10.2307/2234133.

Comment: @AnkitaBanerjea, could you give me the link of the `apsr_fsb.bst` style that you are using. I downloaded it from [here](https://www.nyu.edu/projects/beber/files/apsr_fsb.bst). In my version you can find `FUNCTION{format.num} ` just above `FUNCTION {format.vol.mon.num.pages}`

Comment: the file I am using was downloaded from here: http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/apsr.bst. It seems like you were using a different version perhaps?

Comment: It works now! I used the version you were using and modified the code, and everything looks good. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AnkitaBanerjea, is the update answer works for you?

Comment: yes that's correct!

Comment: Good, enjoy BibteXing :)

Comment: can I ask one additional question related to this? If I want publications by the same author to appear as blanks under the first time the reference appears, is there a way I could modify the .bst file to give me that output?

Comment: @AnkitaBanerjea, please ask another question and give a MWEB.