# Show doi in natbib (apsr) bibliography

Tags: natbib, doi

I am required to meet the requirements of the Chicago style and also show the `doi` field in the bibliography.

So far, I am using `natbib` with `apsr`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep{manski2004measuring}

\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\bibliography{test.bib}

\end{document}
```

The entry in `test.bib` is:

```
@article{manski2004measuring,
  title={Measuring expectations},
  author={Manski, Charles F},
  journal={Econometrica},
  volume={72},
  number={5},
  pages={1329--1376},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library},
  doi={10.1111/j.1468-0262.2004.00537.x}
}
```

The outcome is fine but does not show the `doi`.

> Manski, Charles F. 2004. “Measuring expectations.” *Econometrica*
> 72(5):1329–1376.

How do I include the `doi` field?

Comment: `apsr.bst` seems to date back to 1994 - a few years before DOIs were invented (and a few more before they took off). Unlike the base BibTeX styles it does appear to have support for `url`, though, so it is fairly modern by some standards. Still, you'd have to manually patch in DOI support, which can be a bit painful given the `.bst` programming language. You could try https://www.ctan.org/pkg/urlbst and its Perl script to patch in DOI support - not sure if it works here, though.

Comment: Do you have to use `apsr.bst`? If you can use a different style, you could look into using one that has out-of-the-box support for `doi`. `plainnat` would be one example. I'm pretty sure that `apsr` no longer meets current Chicago Style requirements. If you really need proper Chicago style, you might want to look at `biblatex-chicago` (note that `biblatex` can generally be a problem if you want to submit to publishers - if you do that, ask publisher staff what to do).

Comment: If you need Chicago style and use bibtex, try [chicago style in bibtex](https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-chicago-chicago/). Is Chicago bibtex style not provinding the Chicago style? Editing another bst into another standard is commonly a hard task.

Comment: I am not familiar with this bibliography style, but you can try the following

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435816/formatting-references-journal-articles

with a detailed explanation.